# Missed a letter on the bitcoin address when sending

Tags: transactions

I generated a Bitcoin address from a site and made payment to that address from my PM through an exchange site. The problem is the bitcoin wallet had "h" at the end of it, but I missed it when typing the wallet for payment. The address I intended on sending the payment to has not received the payment due to this error. Have I lost the bitcoin that was sent? I have tried communicating with the exchange site but no luck and the site I was hoping to send payment to has not responded to my emails either.

Comment: Try a blockexplorer and search for both the right address and the wrong address. Try to find your transaction in there. If it was sent to a wrong address, it's lost. But addresses have checksums in them, so I highly doubt that is actually the case.